# Can we switch off the [projector] please?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [projector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/projector) tag has no wiki, and as a result, the 100 questions tagged with it vary wildly in what they presume the word to mean.

So, here we go...

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**

   Unambiguous? Ha. Physical projectors (beamers), light sources in VR, various file formats that call themselves "projector", vague things about other kinds of projections or projects, etc.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   Well, many of the questions are on-topic, that's not the problem.
3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

   Not in its current state, no.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   Nope, see #1.

Now I'm not sure what to do with this one. Many of the questions can be retagged, but does that mean the tag can be burninated? Or should we rename it to mean something more specific?

Simply filling in the wiki is not enough; it's clear that people who add tags to their questions don't read the tag wikis first.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, but has anyone actually asked a question related to _physical projectors (beamers)_?
As for the tag itself... I can't think of a legitimate SO use for it.

Comment: @GabrielLovetro Yes. You can see a list of questions by clicking on the tag; the top one is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43132097/how-to-emulate-media-query-for-projector-on-chrome

Comment: @GabrielLovetro of course that someone asked... luckily they were closed (or so I hope).

Comment: There is [projection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/projection) as one possible destination, altough that one does not have a clear wiki either. Transformation of data into another format is probably what we do every day.

Comment: @ThomasWeller that sounds suspiciously like either [tag:transform] or [tag:transformation]

Comment: Are you sure you're not [projector]ing your feelings onto this tag?

Comment: A good chunk of the questions are about physical projectors and at least some of those have reasonable, on-topic questions.  Another chunk seem to pertain to Adobe Flash Projector, which, if I'm understanding correctly, is a standalone Flash player.  If those groups could be recategorized, I'd have no problem burning the ambiguous tag.

Comment: @GabrielLovetro: perhaps a legitimate question could be about an API to control a beamer (for instance change the lense),...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I would argue that such api is vendor (and probably model) specific, rather than a generic api that projectors have.

Comment: As an AS3 guy, I immediately associated this tag with Adobe's "Flash projector" runtime. A few relevant questions might pertain to why certain swf's don't execute properly offline with the projector. If so, perhaps a rename to "flash-projector" is in order for AS3 cases?